# C# - Shifting and reversing the order of bits in a byte array

Tags: c#, binary, byte, bit, bitarray

I am trying to get the correct int out of an array of bytes.
The bytes is read from a RFIDTag via POS for .Net.
(Acctually I need 18 bits)

In binary the byte array is as follows:
00001110 11011100 00000000 00011011 10000000

What I need to get out of it is:
00 00000000 11101101
(int = 237)

From the original bytes that would be the following bits in reverse order:
------10 11011100 00000000

I have been looking at bitArray. Array.Reverse. And several ways of shifting bits. But I just can't wrap my head around this one.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Why reverse order? Wouldn't `<< 4` shift the desired number into the first byte? A description of the bits would be very helpful and better than just guessing where the desired information is.

Comment: Due to the palindromic bit sequence 1110110111 it's difficult to tell whether you need a reversal or just a bit shift.

Comment: Yeah, unless we get a specification, we'll end in guessing. But it's hard to believe that the bits should be reversed. The bytes, okay, but the bits? Never encountered a situation where the bits were reversed.

Comment: Take a look at this question (and the "best" answer):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654159/extracting-values-across-byte-boundaries-with-arbitrary-bit-positions-and-length

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. But I have no spesification on it. My scenario is this: I have a RFID (iClass) card reader. And I have 5 cards that I can test with. On the cards there is written a number, buth this number is only a part of the actual bytes/bits given when reading it. I use Docklight (http://www.docklight.de/download_en.htm) to  read the card and get what information is on it. I found that to get the number on each card correctly, i need to follow the same procedure on each card. Pick the same 18 bits, and set them in the reversed order. David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the bits and reverse them like this:

```
byte[] data = { 0x0E, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x1B, 0x80 };

// get only first four bytes
byte[] bits = new byte[4];
Array.Copy(data, 0, bits, 0, 4);

// reverse array if system uses little endian
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(bits);
}

// get a 32 bit integer from the four bytes
int n = BitConverter.ToInt32(bits, 0); // 0x0EDC001B

// isolate the 18 bits by shifting and anding
n >>= 8; // 0x000EDC00
n &= 0x0003FFFF; // 0x0002DC00

// reverse by shifting bits out to the right and in from the left
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  result = (result << 1) + (n & 1);
  n >>= 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
237
```

Comment: Thx @Guffa, I'll trye this as soon as I get to work. It seems a lot cleaner than the "none working mess" I came up with yesterday :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
// 00001110 11011100 00000000 00011011 10000000
//    0E       DC       00       1B       80   
byte[] info = new byte[] { 0x0E, 0xDC, 0x00, 0x1B, 0x80 };
int result = (info[0] << 4) | (info[1] >> 4);
Console.WriteLine(result); // ==> 237
```

`info[0] << 4` turns `0E` into `E0`.

`>> 4` turns `DC` into `0D`.

`|` ORs `E0` and `0D` into `ED` which is decimal `237`

Comment: That's not the right bits. It's just a coincidence that those bits give the same result.