# Reording bits in hex value

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I have some hex value which I need to translate but was wandering if there's a quick way of doing so, as an example 11000000 or 0xC0 would need to flip to 00000011 or 0x03, Im not what the name of this type of operation but was hoping something exists.

Comment: Can you describe what you _actually_ want? Just push all of the one's to the right side? Reverse the order of the bits in an 8-bit value?

Comment: I think the bit order should be reversed, so 10100011 --> 11000101

Comment: Yes, it is reversing the bit order, Lsb becomes Msb

Comment: This link answers my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587826/is-there-a-built-in-function-to-reverse-bit-order

Comment: Posting a link (again) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718797/c-sharp-shifting-and-reversing-the-order-of-bits-in-a-byte-array

Answer (score 0):

Silly implementation just for fun:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte b1 = 0xc0;
        IEnumerable<bool> bits = GetBits(b1);
        byte b2 = GetByte(bits);
        byte b3 = GetByte(bits.Reverse());            
    }

    private static IEnumerable<bool> GetBits(byte b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            yield return (b & 0x80).Equals(0x80);
            b = Convert.ToByte((b << 1) & 0xff);
        }
    }

    private static byte GetByte(IEnumerable<bool> bits)
    {
        byte b = 0x00;
        foreach (bool bit in bits)
        {
            b = Convert.ToByte((b << 1) & 0xff);
            if (bit) b = Convert.ToByte((b | 0x01) & 0xff);
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this